# Classes representing figures on a plane

Tags: java

The task is to write a class system that implements figures on the plane (point, segment, square, rectangle, triangle). Also, it is needed to provide encapsulation. There should be constructors and several methods that determine the size. Use the Has-a relationship.

Would you please review my code and say what is not correct here?

```
public class Pres12Task3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape s = new Shape();
    Triangle t = new Triangle(1, 2, 3);
    System.out.println(t.width + "," + t.height + "," + t.getLength());
    t.changeSize(6);
}
}
class Shape {
int X;
int Y;

Shape() {
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
public Shape(int x2, int y2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

void Move(int x, int y) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
}}
class Point extends Shape {
Point(int x, int y) {
    // super();
    Move(x, y);
}}

class Segment extends Shape {
Segment(int x, int y) {
    super();
    Move(x, y);
}}
class Square extends Shape {
int width = 10;

Square(int w, int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
    width = w;
}

void changeSize(int w) {
    width = w;
} }


class Rectangle extends Square {
int height = 9;

Rectangle(int w, int h, int x, int y) {
    super(w, x, y);
    height = h;
}

void changeSize(int w, int h) {
    super.changeSize(w);
    height = h;
}}

class Triangle extends Rectangle {
int length = 7;


Triangle(int l, int w, int h) {
    super(w, h, w, h);
    length = l;
}

public int getLength() {
    return length;
}

public void setLength(int length) {
    if (length > 0) {
        this.length = length;
    } else {
        this.length = 5;
    }
}

void changeSize(int w, int l) {
    super.changeSize(w, l);
    length = l;
}}
```

Comment: A `Rectangle` isn't a `Square` and a `Square` isn't a `Rectangle` (by means of OOP).

Comment: A `Point` is also not a `Shape`. Also, are you aware about something being wrong? It is not clear whether or not this code is working as intended. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. If the code currently does what you want, we can help you do the same thing in a cleaner way, but please clarify whether or not this is working, and I'd also like to know if this is a school assignment or something, and if so what the response from your teacher/professor was.

Comment: @Simon Forsberg  Actually  the  code  works, but  i  am  not  sure  whether i  correctly wrote a part for "Segment" and "Triangle" especially the  part with setters and  getters. Yes this  is  assignment, but my  teacher has  not  seen it  yet. When he  answers  I'll write  his notes  and  corrections  at  this  forum.

Comment: Has-a means that your e.g. triangle class should be along the lines of `class Triangle { Point a, b, c; }` - one class contains other class' objects.

Comment: @Simon Forsberg teacher answered  that class  Shape is not needed here.  two  coordinates of  point should  be  in not in  class shape  but in  class Point.  And  in  class Square there should  be  four  parameters, but  not  three.

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: @ user1803551 I tried  to  do  that, but could't  to  do that properly

Answer (score 1):

## Shape

A Shape is only an abstraction to unify different geometric constructs so my advice would be to make it an abstract class. (that is, a class that you cannot instantiate).

## Point

*Point* as x and y coordinates. That's it. You have to decide if it inherits from *Shape* but from an OOP perspective I do agree with @simon-forsberg that it probably shouldn't.

## Segment

*Segment* is defined by two *Point* and inherits from *Shape*.

## Triangle

*Triangle* is three *Point* and inherits from *Shape*.

And you can keep doing that for *Rectangle* and *Square*, just being careful with how you set up your constructors. Every classes should extend *Shape* but *Point*.

## Encapsulation

When you declare fields like x,y for *Point*, don't forget to give them a visibility modifier like *private* or *protected* (I assume you know what that means?) and then declare appropriate setter/getter.